# What's the best way to persist photo data between pages?

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm setting up a web app which retrieves user data via a 3rd party identity provider (Azure AD). To get the user's photo, I seem to need to make an API call using their access token. Once I get it, what's the best way to store/persist it to show in each view they navigate to?

So far, the only way that I know works at all in terms of showing their photo is to call the Microsoft Graph API to get a photo as a memorystream, convert that to an array of bytes, and then store that as a base 64 string to be later named as an img source. Below is the code that implements the method in question.

```cs
var photoStream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
var sessionPhoto = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
ViewData["photo"] = sessionPhoto;
session.SetString("photo", sessionPhoto);
```

That last line, where I try to store the Base64String in session, is part of my previous attempt at finding a solution. It seems, however, that creating an image from the data saved in `ViewData["photo"]` works fine while attempting to pull from `Session.GetString("photo")` results in a broken image.

In the _Layout view, I have:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

...

@if (ViewData["photo"] != null)
{
   <img class="mr-2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @ViewData["photo"]" />
}
else
{
    var sessionPhoto = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("photo");
    if (sessionPhoto != null)
    {
        <img class="mr-2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, sessionPhoto" />
    }
    else
    {
        <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-3x mr-3"></i>
    }
}
...
```

I expected that getting the string from ViewData["photo"] would yield the same result as getting it from session, but, again, the session version is broken. Also, I'm relatively new to making web apps in .net core and not even sure if session is the best way to store/retrieve the photo, so I'm open to suggestions and alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your session code, you're outputting the string `sessionPhoto` instead of the actual base64 content.

You must update your code to write the value of `sessionPhoto` by pre-pending a `@`:

```
<img class="mr-2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @sessionPhoto" />
```

You should be able to see the issue by viewing the source code of your resulting page.

Comment: I.... I feel so stupid.....thank you. Is session a decent way to be doing this, though? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't know much about the API that you're using to tell you whether that's the best way to do it.  It seems to me that you put it into the session to essentially cache the data and not go to the graph API on every page request, which there are alternate solutions for caching data.  Returning images via inline base64 is probably the least efficient way as the user's browser isn't able to cache the image.  This is probably off topic from the actual question, I'd recommend reading up on caching systems and how to make an HTTP handler that returns the image itself with HTTP caching headers.